# Load a jsp-file from a servlet (App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I would like to load a jsp file from a servlet-class I got in my App Engine project. I has been able to load jsp files by adding them to the web.xml file but is there any way to load them directly from a servlet class?

Edit: 
I have tried this without success (no error msg or anything)
req.getRequestDispatcher("file.jsp").forward(req, resp);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to *include* a JSP in the generated response, use

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/file.jsp").include(request, response);
```

If you want to forward to that jsp, use

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/file.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it myself. Had to add `./` before the filename...

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("./file.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```